# Multiple profiled properties configuration in Spring-boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a spring-boot 2.1.3.RELEASE application with multiple `properties` files.

In my `/src/main/resources` I have `my-app.properties` and profiled `my-app-local.properties`.

Also, outside the project I have another profiled properties file `/config/my-app-local.properties`.

The point of this configuration is to have the following properties hierarchy:

1. `/resources/my-app.properties`
2. `/resources/my-app-local.properties`
3. `/config/my-app-local.properties`

So when I try to run the application with the following parameters:

`--spring.profiles.active=local --spring.config.name=my-app --spring.config.location=config/my-app.properties`

the application fails to start because it can't find any `properties` files.

However, this configuration and parameters worked perfectly on spring-boot 1.5.19.RELEASE. How can the same be achieved in spring-boot 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `spring.config.additional-location` [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

> When custom config locations are configured by using `spring.config.location`, **they replace the default locations.** For example, if `spring.config.location` is configured with the value `classpath:/custom-config/,file:./custom-config/,` the search order becomes the following:

```
file:./custom-config/
classpath:custom-config/
```

> Alternatively, when custom config locations are configured by using `spring.config.additional-location,` they are used in addition to the default locations. Additional locations are searched before the default locations. For example, if additional locations of `classpath:/custom-config/,file:./custom-config/` are configured, the search order becomes the following:

```
file:./custom-config/
classpath:custom-config/
file:./config/
file:./
classpath:/config/
classpath:/
```